# How to store selected time in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an online booking form where users have to type in the start time of an event, and the end time.

I have looked at the documentation for the `TIME type` and it says

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format

Does this mean, that the time entered into the text field will be stored into the `time` field in the database? Since I will need to know what time the user books the room for.

Since html has the `input type time` this will only take the format `HH:MM:SS`, and the `time type` in MySQL only can register this format too i believe.

Would this be a good approach or is there another technique that can register time from user and store it into a database?

Comment: The answer to this question is opinion based. Your approach seems fine to me. You can also store the time as an integer.

Comment: @Halcyon when it comes to comparing time, would you reckon comparing integers would be easier than 'HH:MM:SS' ?

Comment: That will depend on how you code your form's element for it, or how you're going to use a variable to assign to the given time, or that you use the `NOW()` function as part of the insert's value for the respective column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach is good for dealing with time type data. You should use MySQL time type rather than integer or string. There's a bunch of MySQL TIME FUNCTION which can be used and help you when dealing with stored time in db.

You might be facing with comparing time in further, it's like you might be wanna know an overtime booking, available time for next booking, and so on.  For this circumstance, you probably could use one of the MySQL available function: TIMEDIFF function for comparing different time.

This link might helps:
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/date-and-time-functions.php